# Writing to multiple folders in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to separate my output from reducer to different folders..

```
My dirver has the following code:
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));
            //MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, namedOutput, outputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass)
            //MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, namedOutput, outputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass)
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "foo", TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "bar", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class,NullWritable.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "foobar", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, NullWritable.class);

And then my reducer has the following code:
mos.write("foo",NullWritable.get(),new Text(jsn.toString()));
mos.write("bar", key,NullWritable.get());
mos.write("foobar", key,NullWritable.get());

But in the output, I see:

output/foo-r-0001
output/foo-r-0002
output/foobar-r-0001
output/bar-r-0001


But what I am trying is :

output/foo/part-r-0001
output/foo/part-r-0002
output/bar/part-r-0001
```

output/foobar/part-r-0001

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: what version of Hadoop is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean this [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html), the simplest way would be to do one of the following from you reducer --

1. Using named output with a base output path. [See this function](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29).
2. Without named output and using only a base output path, [See this function](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28KEYOUT,%20VALUEOUT,%20java.lang.String%29)

In your case, it's point 1, so, please change the following --

```
mos.write("foo",NullWritable.get(),new Text(jsn.toString()));
mos.write("bar", key,NullWritable.get());
mos.write("foobar", key,NullWritable.get());
```

to,

```
mos.write("foo",NullWritable.get(),new Text(jsn.toString()), "foo/part");
mos.write("bar", key,NullWritable.get(), "bar/part");
mos.write("foobar", key,NullWritable.get(), "foobar/part");
```

Where, *"foo/part"*, *"bar/part"* and *"foobar/part"* corresponds to the baseOutputPath.
Hence, directories foo, bar and foobar would be created and inside that *part-r-xxxxx* files.

You might also try point 2 above, which actually don't need any named output.

Please get back to me for further clarification, if needed.