# Hadoop, MapReduce - Multiple Input/Output Paths

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In my input file when making the Jar for my MapReduce Job, I am using the Hadoop-local command. I wanted to know whether there was a way of, instead of specifically specifying the path for each file in my input folder to be used in the MapReduce job, whether I could just specify and pass all the files from my input folder. This is because the contents and number of files could change due to the nature of the MapReduce job I am trying to configure and as I do not know the specific amount of files, apart from just the contents of these files, is there a way to pass all files from the input folder into my MapReduce program and then iterate over each file to compute a certain function which would then send the results to the Reducer. I am only using one Map/Reduce program and I am coding in Java. I am able to use the hadoop-moonshot command, but I am working with hadoop-local at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: If you specify an HDFS directory in your job instead of a file, then all the files should be read. Can you please [edit] your question to include the command you are running? Maybe some code in a [mcve], also?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 could you perhaps provide an example of a call to the HDFS directory instead of a single file please. Also, how would I have a separate output file for each input. I'm guessing it's by using the MultipleOutput class somehow, but I can't see how at the moment.

Comment: I cant remember how to output multiple files, but the mapreduce output itself must be to one directory. As for directory input, the [wordcount example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage) reads two files from one directory

Comment: @Shah.1 have you tried setting: `FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(mapReduceJob, true);` to be able to read the files recursively?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass individual file as input for `MapReduce` Job.

[FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html#addInputPath(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) class already provides API to accept list of multiple files as Input to Map Reduce program.

```
public static void setInputPaths(Job job,
                 Path... inputPaths)
                          throws IOException
```

> Add a Path to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.
>   Parameters:
>
> conf - The configuration of the job
>
> path - Path to be added to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

Example code from Apache [tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

[MultipleInputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) provides below APIs.

```
public static void addInputPath(Job job,
                Path path,
                Class<? extends InputFormat> inputFormatClass,
                Class<? extends Mapper> mapperClass)
```

> Add a Path with a custom InputFormat and Mapper to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

Related SE question:

[Can hadoop take input from multiple directories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445366/can-hadoop-take-input-from-multiple-directories-and-files)

Refer to [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) API regarding your second query on multiple output paths.

```
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outDir);

// Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
LongWritable.class, Text.class);

// Defines additional sequence-file based output 'sequence' for the job
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "seq",
SequenceFileOutputFormat.class,
LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

Have a look at related SE questions regarding multiple output files.

[Writing to multiple folders in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328136/writing-to-multiple-folders-in-hadoop)

[hadoop method to send output to multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820985/hadoop-method-to-send-output-to-multiple-directories)

Comment: That example code you pulled only uses one input path

Comment: Except in title of the question which says both Input/Output, OP is looking for multiple files as Input in the body of question. No mention of Output. Later I have added setOutputPath API.

Comment: The title and the question don't really match, though. All that was asked was reading a directory of files. Which, yes, this code can do. I was simply saying that you mention the multiple paths, but the example code doesn't use that method

Comment: Thanks @Ravindrababu but how I would use that to pass in multiple input files. And how would I specify multiple output files, each outputting to a different directory. Let's say a different text file outputting the results for each input.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Ravindrababu thank you for your answer I am currently going through it. However, how the FileInputFormat still only inputs one file which is args[0]. How do I get it to input all the files from input.